# Track cookie initiator or intercept cookie creation

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to figure out how I can track which script(s)/domains are setting cookies in a puppeteer session.  I'm attempting to map activities (cookies/DOM mutations/network calls/etc) from included libraries to visualise the potential impact they have on the performance of our website.

It's easy to list them out via the `Network.getAllCookies` command against a [`CDPSession`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.cdpsession) or simply using [`await page.cookies`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.cookies) but those only show me what's been set, not what set them.

I've tried to take a look at the Chrome Devtools protocol monitor but again, I can't actually see an event fire when a cookie is set.  It's feasible to extract a `Set-Cookie` header from a response but that won't help if the cookie's set through `document.cookie` within an embedded script.

**Edit - added some sample code:**

It's a bit difficult to demo given it requires both a publicly accessible website and a third party library that sets cookies, but this repo attempts to do illustrate the issue: https://github.com/m3rls/cookie-example

- There's a Github pages file in `/docs` ([index.html](https://github.com/m3rls/cookie-example/blob/main/docs/index.html)) that maps to https://m3rls.github.io/cookie-example/
- That Github pages HTML includes an instance of [LogRocket](https://logrocket.com/) via a `<head>` script include.  LogRocket sets a few cookies when it's initialised (prefixed by `_lr_`) but these are *not* set locally - they're set via the obfuscated LogRocket JavaScript lib via `document.cookie`.
- There's also a very basic puppeteer script ([script.js](https://github.com/m3rls/cookie-example/blob/main/script.js)) in the repo that will load that Github pages URL referenced above and log out the CDPSession requests, and then at the end log out both methods of cookie retrieval.  This can be run via `node script.js` after an `npm install`.

It'd be ideal if there was an `initiator` linked to the cookies but the closest thing I have is `domain` which is just where the cookie's scoped, so it's of no use unfortunately.

Comment: please post your code so that we can try out ourselves

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited my post with a repo that hopefully illustrates the issue now

Comment: please add the actual code with a small and reproducible example not a git repository

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way I can think of to provide a reproducible example that's any more concise than the example in that repo.  The script (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/m3rls/cookie-example/main/script.js) is a single file, 32 line node example..

Comment: To be honest after spending another few hours trialling various things I think this question is actually not really puppeteer specific at all - given it's working as designed - and I'm instead going to need to use `page.evaluateOnNewDocument()` and some JavaScript to intercept the document.cookie setter via `Object.defineProperty`, and try to determine the callee that way.

Comment: It sounds like you should be looking at [coverage](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.coverage.startjscoverage)